# Adding data to my database row by row from a different list

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm making another attempt to insert the data into my freshly constructed spell trap table and my first table from an array. Unfortunately, errors continue to happen. While it claims that not all parameters were utilised in the SQL statement, I'm quite sure I did. I double-checked the lists to see if I had made any mistakes, but there don't appear to be any. After that, I compared my for loop, which is quite similar to the one I used to enter data into my database before, and found no errors. Please, could yanyone help? It's meant to place items from the list into the appropriate columns in both table. I placed items into the cards table already linked with item placed in another table I created call card details.

This is what I tried

```py
Yugiohspelltraps = [("1st Movement Solo", "SPELL"), #list of data for card table
               ("A Wingbeat of Giant Dragon", "SPELL"),
               ("Polymerization", "SPELL"),
               ("Xyz Revenge", "SPELL"),
               ("Zombie World", "SPELL"),
               ("A Hero Emerges", "TRAP"),
               ("Blackbird Close", "TRAP")]

Yghcardsspelltrapdetails = [("Normal Spell", "If you control no monsters: Special Summon 1 Level 4 or lower Melodious monster from your hand or Deck. You can only activate 1 1st Movement Solo per turn. You cannot Special Summon monsters during the turn you activate this card, except Melodious monsters."), #list of data for spell trap table
                   ("Normal Spell", "Return 1 Level 5 or higher Dragon-Type monster you control to the hand, and if you do, destroy all Spell and Trap Cards on the field."),
                   ("Normal Spell", "Fusion Summon 1 Fusion Monster from your Extra Deck, using monsters from your hand or field as Fusion Material."),
                   ("Normal Spell", "If your opponent controls a face-up Xyz Monster that has Xyz Material: Target 1 Xyz monster in your Graveyard; Special Summon it, then detach 1 Xyz Material from a monster your opponent controls and attach it to that monster as an Xyz Material. You can only activate 1 Xyz Revenge per turn."),
                   ("Field Spell", "All monsters on the field and in the GYs become Zombie monsters. Neither player can Tribute Summon monsters, except Zombie monsters."),
                   ("Normal trap", "When an opponent's monster declares an attack: Your opponent chooses 1 random card from your hand, then if it is a monster that can be Special Summoned, Special Summon it. Otherwise, send it to the GY."),
                   ("Counter Trap", "When a monster your opponent controls activates its effect: You can send 1 face-up Blackwing monster you control to the GY; negate the activation, and if you do, destroy it, then, you can Special Summon 1 Black-Winged Dragon from your Extra Deck. If you control a Blackwing Synchro Monster or Black-Winged Dragon, you can activate this card from your hand.")]

Q3 = "INSERT INTO Cards (Cardname, Cardtype) VALUES (%s, %s)"#Query for inserting vaules into Cardname and Cardtype columns

Q11 = """CREATE TABLE Spelltrap (SpelltrapID int PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY(SpelltrapID) REFERENCES Cards(cardID), 
                    speedspell VARCHAR(50), 
                    stflavourtext VARCHAR(7000))""" #Creates the Card details table

Q12 = "INSERT INTO Spelltrap (speedspell, stflavourtext) VALUES (%s, %s)"#Query for inserting vaules into columns of spelltrap table

for x, Yugiohspelltrap in enumerate(Yugiohspelltraps):
    mycursor.execute(Q3, Yugiohspelltrap)
    last_id = mycursor.lastrowid
    mycursor.execute(Q12, (last_id,) + Yghcardsspelltrapdetails[x]) #loops through array of data and inserts them into columns from in both table linked correctly by primary and foregin key.
```

This is what I recieved

```py
    mycursor.execute(Q12, (last_id,) + Yghcardsspelltrapdetails[x]) #loops through array of data and inserts them into columns from in both table linked correctly by primary and foregin key.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: SQL query `Q12` contains two placeholders but including `last_id` you provide three parameters. It seems you forgot the `SpelltrapID` in the SQL query.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I didn't need to do that. Since I didn't need to do it the previous time I did something like this.